# Linking prebuilt static libraries ndk vs. Android source

Tags: android, android-ndk, linker, static-libraries

I have found recently that linking prebuilt static libraries from the ndk-build is fundamentally different than from within the android source tree (mm). Why is this?

```
   // main.cpp
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include "doubler.hpp"

    int main()
    {
       printf("test a static lib \n");

       // library function
       doubler *p = new doubler();
       delete p;

       return 0;
    }
```

Android mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

###################### static lib ##################
### prebuilt lib works in NDK but not Android src
#include $(CLEAR_VARS)
#LOCAL_MODULE := doubleIt_prebuilt
#LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  $(LOCAL_PATH)/libDoubler.a
#LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)
##LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  libDoubler.a
#include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

###################### test app ##################
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# binary name
LOCAL_MODULE:= testApp

# c++ file extension
LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cpp

# src files
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp

# include dir
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)

### this works in Android src, but not in NDK 
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(LOCAL_PATH) -lDoubler

### prebuilt lib works in NDK but not Android src
#LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := doubleIt_prebuilt

#what to build
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Ultimately, what is the correct way to link a static lib in the src tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is this?

ndk-build and the AOSP build system are two entirely different build systems that unfortunately look very similar.

> Ultimately, what is the correct way to link a static lib in the src tree?

In the AOSP tree? Prebuilt modules are defined differently. Here are a couple examples:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/sdk/+/9c011b3a7784803b96dc0f0a840aa9033a0cd62a/tools/Android.mk#291

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libbcc
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(HOST_OS)/lib64/$(LOCAL_MODULE)$(HOST_SHLIB_SUFFIX)
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := SHARED_LIBRARIES
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(HOST_SHLIB_SUFFIX)
LOCAL_IS_HOST_MODULE := true
LOCAL_MULTILIB := 64
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/518e6c3a28cc63fd094c8b255e268650b03fdab5/host/windows/prebuilt/usb/Android.mk

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_IS_HOST_MODULE := true
LOCAL_MODULE := AdbWinApi
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := STATIC_LIBRARIES
LOCAL_SRC_FILES_x86 := AdbWinApi.a
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := .a
LOCAL_MULTILIB := 32
LOCAL_MODULE_HOST_OS := windows
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

You then use them the same way you would any other library: `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libmyprebuilt`. Both of the above examples are for host modules. For a target module simply remove that line.

Note that AOSP's new (still in progress) build system, Soong, does not yet have support for prebuilt modules. These can only be defined in Android.mk files right now.

Comment: This works. Thanks!
Worth noting is the LOCAL_IS_HOST_MODULE will seemingly tell the build system this module is part of the host/tree? So if you provide your own static lib, leave this line out